# Can't manipulate Screen Manager on Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, mobile-application

I'm really new to Kivy and started learning yersterday, but came across a problem I found no solution for. I know I can make ScreenManagers switch between screens using app.root.current. However, my Screen Manager is inside a Box Layout, so I've tried self.parent.current and similar variants but I still can't get it to work. Here is a simplified version of my .kv file which contains all the necessary information related to my problem.

```
Principal:

<Principal@BoxLayout>
    orientation: "vertical"
    TopLayout
        size_hint: 1,.18
    Ventanas
        id: ventanas

<Ventanas@ScreenManager>
    Actividades
        name: "Actividades"
        Label:
            text: "test1"
    Planes
        name: "Planes"
        Label:
            text: "test2"
    Estadisticas
        name: "Estadísticas"
        Label:
            text: "test2"

<TopLayout@RelativeLayout>
    # Navegador is a Spinner Dropdown
    Navegador:
        id: navegador
        text: ""
        background_color: (0,0,1,1)
        color: (0,0,0,0)
        size_hint: .3,0.95
        pos_hint: {"x":0.05,"top":0.975}
        values: 'Actividades', 'Planes', 'Estadísticas'
        on_text:
            app.root.ventanas.current = navegador.text
```

I would really like to find a solution which doesn't imply setting the Screen Manager as the main layout, as I don't like the transitions affecting every element on screen.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `app.root.ids.ventana.current = navegador.text`.

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thank you. @JohnAnderson